# Import all imports in eclipse at once?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

Okay, I recently started learning Java/Android so I look up a lot of tutorials and do a lot of copying/pasting, but most of the times the tutorial doesn't have the imports imported, so I have to go down the line clicking all the errors then Import this, import that, import something else! So... my question: Is there a way to import all of them at once?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

On Windows you can use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>   which is a shortcut to Organize imports

On Mac it is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Thanks orip)

Comment: Thanks! Work's great, except I press Commands + Shift + O ... cause I have a mac...lol :)

Comment: It is not available in Oxygen 4.7

Answer (score 11):

Use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  to see the list of shortcuts available

Comment: +1 for solving the need to ask questions like this in the future

Answer (score 2):

There are classes that have same name but do different work. See how many classes `Date`. At first time this looks not comfortably, but you will get used very fast.
You can organize your imports automatickly, in NetBeans I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>  hotkey. There must be analog in other IDE`s.

Also importing a whole package (like this: `java.util.*`) is a bad practice

Answer (score 2):

You have some shortcuts on eclipse, look this page.

http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm

I hope it help you, there you have the shortcuts named before for they and others more.

Sorry for mi English I hope it help you.

Comment: The link is expired

Answer (score 0):

`alt(option) + enter(return)` for Android Studio in mac system.